# Java - How to mock static block with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

Suppose I have legacy ElasticSearchIndexManager that is `Singleton` with `static block` as in the picture below that cannot be changed. My goal is to create a mock with any framework supported by latest java JDK.

Previously we used `PowerMock` that did the job as it had the ability to create `mockStaticPartial` that eliminated the static block at the startup of ElasticSearchIndexManager as in the code below.

```
PowerMock.mockStaticPartial(ElasticSearchIndexManager.class, "getInstance");
        EasyMock.expect(
                ElasticSearchIndexManager.getInstance(EasyMock.anyObject(AWSRegion.class)))
                .andReturn(null).anyTimes();
```

[image]

The problem is that `PowerMock` is not supported with higher versions of JDK.

Now I've tried to use Mockito 3.7.7 and it helped a bit but did not solve my issue. Because we have legacy code in a static block. In PowerMock we eliminate it by using mockStaticPartial.

POM.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

// New code - with 3.7.7 Mockito
    @Test
        public void testMockElasticSearchIndexManager() {
            AWSRegion region = mock(AWSRegion.class);
    
            try (MockedStatic<ElasticSearchIndexManager> theMock = Mockito.mockStatic(ElasticSearchIndexManager.class)) {
                theMock.when(() -> ElasticSearchIndexManager.getInstance(region)).thenReturn(null);
            }

        assertEquals(null, ElasticSearchIndexManager.getInstance(region));
    }
```

Maybe I missed something? I get this exception before assertion: `org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Cannot instrument class com.cloudally.index.ElasticSearchIndexManager because it or one of its supertypes could not be initialized`

If I remove the `static block` it will work. Is there any similar ability to create a partial static mock with `Mockito`?
Else, other ways are also welcome.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have seen similar behaviour - you're right that the contents of the static block here is significant. Can you post the full stack trace that you're getting when you receive the `MockitoException`? In my case, the cause was highlighted in the full stack trace, as there was a Null Pointer Exception being thrown due to an uninstantiated Singleton object that hadn't been initialised in the test environment. The solution to this was to add in another mock for my singleton class.

Comment: This was was my workaround I did another mocks that are in static block. But my question is maybe there is build-in mock like in PowerMock (mockStaticPartial)

Answer (score -1):

Can you try?

```
try (MockedStatic<ElasticSearchIndexManager> theMock = Mockito.mockStatic(ElasticSearchIndexManager.class)) {
    theMock.when(() -> ElasticSearchIndexManager.getInstance(region)).thenReturn(null);
    assertEquals(null, ElasticSearchIndexManager.getInstance(region));
}
```

Mock context is active only inside the try-with-resource block. When it goes outside the scope, it gets closed.